# SSH Access from outside of network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I'm able to SSH into my network using my DDNS, which takes me into my NAS.  However, I also have my Windows PC and my Linux PC on that network.  I want to SSH into them from outside of the network, however my IP/DDNS takes me to the NAS, how can I specify which machine to SSH into, without being on a VPN.

I use

```
ssh -i /path/to/rsa/key user@ddns.com
```

or

```
ssh -i /path/to/rsa/key user@ip
```

I want to be able to differentiate between which machine I'm SSHing into, as their addresses are 192.168.1.103, 192.168.1.110, and 192.168.1.135 which is the NAS.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not a question for [so]. Try asking on [su]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use tunneling, if you can connect to NAS via SSH.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)